# Matching complex inheritance-y thing

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

I have a kind of complex inheritance-y thing I'm trying to match in Rust:

```
struct Entity {
    pub kind: EntityKind,
}

pub enum EntityKind {
    Player(PlayerData),
}

pub struct PlayerData {
    pub name: String,
}
```

How do I match it with the pattern matching stuff, for instance:

```
// pretend theres a vector of entities called E
match E[i] {
    // match PlayerKind,
    // match another kind here
}
```

How would I do that so I can get the PlayerData when E[i] is a Player enum item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution while keeping your design with newtypes ([learn more about newtypes](https://aturon.github.io/features/types/newtype.html)):

```
struct Entity {
    pub kind: EntityKind,
}

pub enum EntityKind {
    Player(PlayerData),
    Weapon(WeaponData),
}

pub struct PlayerData {
    pub name: String,
}

pub struct WeaponData {
    pub damage_per_shot: i32,
}

fn f(e: EntityKind) {
    match e {
        EntityKind::Player(player_data) => { /* do sth with player data */ },
        EntityKind::Weapon(weapon_data) => { /* do sth with weapon data */ },
    }
}
```

[(Playground)](http://is.gd/ud2i0e)

---

However, I would rather leverage the trait system for that:

```
struct Entity {
    pub kind: EntityKind,
}

pub trait EntityKind { 
    fn do_something(&self); // or &mut self, if needed
}

pub struct PlayerData {
    pub name: String,
}
impl EntityKind for PlayerData {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        // do sth with player data
    }
}

pub struct WeaponData {
    pub damage_per_shot: i32,
}
impl EntityKind for WeaponData {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        // do sth with weapon data
    }
}

// Dynamic dispatch version
fn f(e: &EntityKind) {
    e.do_something();
}

// Static dispatch version (a la C++ template)
fn g<E: EntityKind>(e: E) {
    e.do_something();
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! And also that trait stuff looks great, I'll give it a shot! :)

Comment: To note: In your second example, storing directly a trait in `Entity` makes it unsized, which can have a lot of undesirable effects.

Comment: That's right, in this case two alternatives are 1) `Entity<E: EntityKind>` (not very versatile, but works) and 2) `pub kind: Box<EntityKind>`, but this adds an indirection overhead (and heap alloc upon construction)